# The pop windows when netload dll in cad2014

Tags: c#, cad

When I netload a dll file in CAD2014,It always pop a window which let me confirm. I want to netload a dll file without a prompt window. How to do it?Please comment to help me.It will so great,if someone can give me an example.

I have searched on net,but no use.

If someone can solve my problem,I will be so appreciated.

Comment: Please use code to solve my problem.Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution that add a trust path for CAD:

```
 public void gettrust()
    {
        string str_TR = (string)Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.GetSystemVariable("TRUSTEDPATHS");
        string C_Paths = str_TR.ToLower();
        List<string> Old_Path_Ary = new List<string>();
        Old_Path_Ary = new List<string>(C_Paths.Split(new char[] { ';' }));

        String curfile = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        String curDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(curfile);   //the directory need to add.
        if (!Old_Path_Ary.Contains(curDirectory))
        {
            Old_Path_Ary.Add(curDirectory);
        }
        Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.SetSystemVariable("TRUSTEDPATHS", string.Join(";", Old_Path_Ary.ToArray()));
    }
```